# Inconsistencies Loading Pickle File Between Machines

Tags: python, pycharm, pickle

I have two machines, a PC and a laptop both using pycharm, running the same script trying to load the same pickle file. On one machine, I can run the script with no problems. On the other computer, I end up with the following error:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Below are the versions I'm using:

Desktop:

pycharm build: #PY-202.6397.98

Pycharm: 2020.2

Interpreter: Anaconda3: 3.8

Laptop:

pycharm build: #PY-101.7319.64

Pycharm: 2020.2.2

Interpreter: Anaconda3: 3.8

File Size: 93 KB

Data structure: Dictionary of lists

Both devices have more than enough memory, and the file itself isn't even that large. If I increase the recursionlimit, I end up with a stackoverflow memory error, however my available memory is quite high.

Does anyone here have any information on why or how this might be happening? I haven't updated anything recently and nothing should have changed. I really am kind of perplexed on this one.

Comment: What type of objects are in the lists? Fundamental types or other class instances?

Comment: Can you post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the error with your setup?

Comment: As far as types go it’s a dictionary where each key is a string and each value is a pandas data frame. In this particular list it’s only 30 or so keys and thus 30 or so dataframes. 

Not sure I can show the minimum amount of code to reproduce other than doing a pickle.load on a file to open

Answer (score 0):

After some time digging around, I did find an answer to this. It seemed the problem lied between how the file was created and loaded, specifically with the interpreter. Even more specifically, if I used a pickle file created by a virtual environment it would not work with my base Anaconda3 version. By instead having all my machines use virtual environments I was able to correctly consume my pickle files.